# Can't set breakpoints on an auto-property setter ? Why?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, debugging, breakpoints, automatic-properties

Apparently VS 2008 does not allow setting a breakpoint just on the setter of an auto-property.

I.e. if I define an auto-property like this:

```
    public int CurrentFramesize
    {
        get; 
        protected set;
    }
```

and then try to set a breakpoint on the setter line, the whole auto-property turns breakpoint-red.

This works just fine for normal properties, so any idea why auto-properties get this special (restrictive) treatment? Are they more than just syntactic sugar to normal properties with a hidden backing field?

Comment: You are correct.  I noticed the same thing.

Comment: Microsoft's response http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/408762/unable-to-set-breakpoint-to-c-automatic-property

Comment: I was desparately hoping ths feature would make it into VS2010 :(

Comment: @bitbonk ... and I assume it didn't? :(

Comment: You are assuming correctly. It still doesn't work in VS 2010.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging automatic properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408110/debugging-automatic-properties)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using Visual Studio 2008, 2010, 2012:

1. Go to the Breakpoint window
2. New->Break at Function…
3. For the get,
   type: `ClassName.get_CurrentFramesize()`

   For the set, type: `ClassName.set_CurrentFramesize(int)`

You'll get a "No Source Available" when the breakpoint is hit, but you'll get the calling location in the call stack.

I found this solution here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/b1dd0dc3-e9c1-402a-9c79-a5abf7f7286a

See also: [Debugging automatic properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408110/debugging-automatic-properties)

Comment: Somehow I missed your answer for two and a half years. +1 and accepted! :)

Comment: Works in Visual Studio 2019, (the point 2. being New-> Function Breakpoint...

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: this <strike>bug</strike> feature ended up on the cutting room floor for VS2008.

(Longer [answer](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/408762/unable-to-set-breakpoint-to-c-automatic-property) - hat tip @jdk)

All we've got is a vague promise that it's being considered for vNext.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is implemented in Visual Studio 2015

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/14/set-breakpoints-on-auto-implemented-properties-with-visual-studio-2015.aspx

Answer (score -3):

No you can't set a break point on them, but then what would you check? The variable for storage of the auto-property is only assigned at runtime and as such there isn't a variable for the debugger to show/access.

Comment: You might want to check *when* it's assigned, if it seems to get a wrong value from "somewhere".

Comment: @Hans Kesting: Spot on. The CLR debugger doesn't have *data* breakpoints, so if this would be supported, it would be the next best thing.