# Im using break point but it never get to the first line in the class

Tags: c#

This is the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Net;

namespace GatherLinks
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A result encapsulating the Url and the HtmlDocument
    /// </summary>
    class WebPage
    {
        public Uri Url { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get every WebPage.Internal on a web site (or part of a web site) visiting all internal links just once
        /// plus every external page (or other Url) linked to the web site as a WebPage.External
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Use .OfType WebPage.Internal to get just the internal ones if that's what you want
        /// </remarks>
        public  static IEnumerable<WebPage> GetAllPagesUnder(Uri urlRoot)
        {
            var queue = new Queue<Uri>();
            var allSiteUrls = new HashSet<Uri>();

            queue.Enqueue(urlRoot);
            allSiteUrls.Add(urlRoot);

            while (queue.Count > 0)
            {
                Uri url = queue.Dequeue();

                HttpWebRequest oReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                oReq.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5";

                HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)oReq.GetResponse();

                WebPage result;

                if (resp.ContentType.StartsWith("text/html", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
                    try
                    {
                        var resultStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
                        doc.Load(resultStream); // The HtmlAgilityPack
                        result = new Internal() { Url = url, HtmlDocument = doc };
                    }
                    catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
                    {
                        result = new WebPage.Error() { Url = url, Exception = ex };
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ex.Data.Add("Url", url);    // Annotate the exception with the Url
                        throw;
                    }

                    // Success, hand off the page
                    yield return new WebPage.Internal() { Url = url, HtmlDocument = doc };

                    // And and now queue up all the links on this page
                    foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//a[@href]"))
                    {
                        HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
                        if (att == null) continue;
                        string href = att.Value;
                        if (href.StartsWith("javascript", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) continue;      // ignore javascript on buttons using a tags

                        Uri urlNext = new Uri(href, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

                        // Make it absolute if it's relative
                        if (!urlNext.IsAbsoluteUri)
                        {
                            urlNext = new Uri(urlRoot, urlNext);
                        }

                        if (!allSiteUrls.Contains(urlNext))
                        {
                            allSiteUrls.Add(urlNext);               // keep track of every page we've handed off

                            if (urlRoot.IsBaseOf(urlNext))
                            {
                                queue.Enqueue(urlNext);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                yield return new WebPage.External() { Url = urlNext };
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ///// <summary>
        ///// In the future might provide all the images too??
        ///// </summary>
        //public class Image : WebPage
        //{
        //}

        /// <summary>
        /// Error loading page
        /// </summary>
        public class Error : WebPage
        {
            public int HttpResult { get; set; }
            public Exception Exception { get; set; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// External page - not followed
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// No body - go load it yourself
        /// </remarks>
        public class External : WebPage
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Internal page
        /// </summary>
        public class Internal : WebPage
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// For internal pages we load the document for you
            /// </summary>
            public virtual HtmlDocument HtmlDocument { get; internal set; }
        }
    }
}
```

It never stop on this line:

```
public Uri Url { get; set; }
```

And never stop on any other lines in this class. Only if i remove the line:

```
public Uri Url { get; set; }
```

Then it stop on other lines. But i dont get it why it dosent stop on the first line ? How can i fix it ?

I tried ot read about automatic properties but i didnt understand what it is and i didnt want to use it in this class.

Comment: Break point will only stop on a code inside a method.

Answer (score 1):

Breakpoints are [not supported](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/vsdebug/thread/b1dd0dc3-e9c1-402a-9c79-a5abf7f7286a) on [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx). Try setting it in the first line of the `GetAllPagesUnder` method.

Comment: @AndrasZoltan - I missed the inheriting classes. Thanks.

Comment: yeah not surprising, there's a lot to look at :)

Comment: @AndrasZoltan - heh. First time I wanted to use [Stack Overflow is not going to read all that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/140505)...

Comment: Lol - I have like the links you've been adding on the questions that deserve them that point to that meta :)

Comment: @AndrasZoltan - Yeah, that meta was created with that kind of usage in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the breakpoint to where you declare this class.

```
WebPage wp =new WebPage();
```

because as Asif said above, it wont stop in a declaration.

Or after you declare the Class set the Url variable

```
wp.Url="blahblahblah.html";
```

EDIT: I was unaware of breakpoints not working on auto properties.
change your

```
public Uri Url{get;set;}
```

to

```
private Uri _Url=new Uri();
public Url URL{get{return _Url;}set{_Url = value;}}
```

what you are doing here is creating a private variable name _Url and accessing it with the property Url

use is

```
Url="blahblahblah";
```

same as you are currently using it

Answer (score 0):

It's very vague from your question - but I have a hunch that somewhere in your program you're calling:

```
var results = WebPage.GetAllPagesUnder([some uri]);
```

And you're expecting breakpoints to be hit when that method is called?

It won't - it's yielding an enumerator.  The code doesn't actually do anything until you `foreach` the enumerable; or perhaps eager load it via `ToArray`, `ToList` or something similar.

As for the automatic property, no you can't breakpoint that - but then you shouldn't ever need to - just breakpoint the code that is setting the property instead.  If you *really* want to, stick in a private backing field and implement the property manually.  Failing that, give the class a constructor that takes the `Uri` and sets it, then you breakpoint that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a breakpoint at the `Url` property like it is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6713867/451540).

The standard way of setting a breakpoint does not work for auto properties.