# How does one break inside a default c# getter or setter?

Tags: c#, debugging, getter-setter

I'm debugging something and I need to know when something is being set. There seems to be no explicit set, as in x = 5. So would there be anyway to make sure that it is not getting set? Specifically by breaking in the default setter?

If the question wasn't clear enough:

```
public FooClass
{ 

    FooClass() { }

    public int x { get; set; } //How do I break in the setting of this property?
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking on the line of the property and setting a breakpoint there?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't get hit. However, this could be because it simply isn't getting set. Unless of course you know that setting a breakpoint on that line should work.

Comment: You can find the instructions in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408110/debugging-automatic-properties)

Answer (score 4):

You can forcefully cause the Debugger to break:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Debugger.Break();
```

You may have to expand your auto property with an explicit backing field though:

```
public class FooClass {
    private int _x;

    public int X {
        get {
            return _x;
        }
        set {
            _x = value;
            Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
}
```

..or, just expand the property out (like above) and put a breakpoint there yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If there's code inside your getter or setter you can break there so you can create a private member for the property.

```
private int _x;
public int X {
    get { 
        return _x;
    }
    set {
        _x = value;
    }
}
```

That'll allow you to put breaks on the return _x and _x = value lines.

Comment: Perfect! Not sure why I didn't think of that!