# Autoproperty debugging

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, properties

When I use autoproperty for example

```
public string Prop {get;set;}
```

compiler generates two functions: get_Prop() and set_Prop(string val). I would like to set breakpoint on one from this function. When I set breakpoint by function this function name debuger never enter in this functions. Intellisense doesn't work in my dialog (Ctrl+B)

My questions:
1) Where compiler save source code with replaced property to function? If it do this.
2) Why Intelisense not working?
3) How to set breakpoint on this functons?

I use VS2013 Ultimate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging automatic properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408110/debugging-automatic-properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) the compiler don't save source code, it compiles. The implicit backing fields are only present in the IL code.

2) It's a feature, not a bug, I agree it could be great.

3) You have to create a backing field manually in order to put a breakpoint on it.

```
private string _prop;
public string Prop
{
    get { return _prop; }
    set { _prop= value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a great solution described here:

[Debugging automatic properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408110/debugging-automatic-properties?lq=1)

Basically, you can set a breakpoint with Breapooint->Create New and put it on

ClassName.set_PropertyName 
or
ClassName.get_PropertyName.

It is also available in Visual Studio 2015, or for earlier versions you can use VS plugins such as Oz Code to do this automatically (break on setter)

[image]