# Visual Studio is missing/moving my breakpoints

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

The problem is that when I place a breakpoint and debug/run, the breakpoint moves by itself.

Before/whilst coding:

[image]

After clicking run/breakpoint hit:

[image]

Breakpoints typically work ok for me, but it seems that they sometimes randomly play up. I first had this ages ago with a VB project, and in the end, I bypassed the problem by removing the breakpoint and adding it somewhere else where it was still useful.

Whilst I could probably do the same again, and this is only the second time it has happened (that I remember), I don't really want to have to and would like to know what is actually wrong.

I have read through many similar questions here, but I cannot see an exact match and the answers do not help. I have tried - building, rebuilding, closing/reopening and cleaning.

I only provided a picture of the bit of code where it occurs, if you need anything else, please let me know.

Comment: It is now 2019, and Visual Studio 2019 is still moving breakpoints

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because the debugger isn't able to break at that point. For example, the debugger can't break on auto-implemented properties, or at the header of a method; instead, it breaks at the first line of the method.

Comment: I was really hoping it would break when there was a change/id was set. IF I extend the set method, would I be able to set a breakpoint there?

Comment: @Wil You could always set a conditional breakpoint that will break when the value of `Result` changes (right-click the breakpoint and pick "Condition...")

Comment: I accepted, but I don't suppose you can explain a little more. Why is it stopping at the next method which is unrelated? / and are conditional breakpoints the best solution? I tried the solution above, but the breakpoint still moves / does not occur at that point.

Comment: @Wil: It's just putting the breakpoint at the next valid place; it doesn't care what method it's in. Also, I don't think that making the breakpoint conditional changes anything; it still can't stop at an auto-implemented property.

Comment: To set a breakpoint for an auto-implemented property see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682613/cant-set-breakpoints-on-an-auto-property-setter-why/6713920#6713920

Answer (score 12):

Also check to see if you had set the breakpoints in one mode (Debug) but are now in a different mode (like Release).  This caused me some momentary angst.

Comment: Your remark is more suitable as a comment, since it is not an actual answer. (I aware you can't comment yet).

Comment: This was actually the cause of the my problem. You're the champ Mike. Thanks.

Comment: Have spent the past 2 days screaming at Visual Studio all because my project had been set on Release. Thanks

Comment: this particular mistake messed up at least 5 hours of mine

Answer (score 3):

I got this problem after Windows had inexplicably added 6 months to the current system date (and 1 hour to the time). I didn't correct this right away, so builds made before the correction looked more recent to Visual. This lead to running the wrong (older) build when debugging.

Since I couldn't find a "**Clean Solution/Project**" option, I had to manually delete all .pdb files in the solution. The problem was instantly fixed. I just hope there aren't any more files I might need to delete (I'm new to Visual and don't know much about how it works behind the scenes).

Comment: "Build > Clean Solution" (How so you cannot find that option?)

Answer (score 0):

You can get this if the breakpoint is AFTER a return statement. Visual Studio will bounce the breakpoint to the closing brace (or "End Function" for VB.NET) because return is jumping out of the function.

Answer (score 0):

for `Visual Studio Code` users, it might be related to TS/NODE :

- `--nolazy` flag, so you have to pass it (more info at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62501780/2377343 )
- `sourceMap` flag (more at: https://github.com/hbenl/vscode-mocha-test-adapter/issues/189#issuecomment-1024449697 )