# What does the Node.js `--nolazy` flag mean?

Tags: node.js, node-debugger

When I use `--nolazy`, I can finally debug asynchronously with IntelliJ, as breakpoints stop at the correct place. But I can't find any docs on `--nolazy`...

What does `--nolazy` mean?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

To let anyone know, if you debug node js (especially remote debug) and use async type coding which you kind of have to as this is the nature of node, you will to run node with the flag of -nolazy

```
node --nolazy --debug-brk sample1.js
```

this will force V8 engine to do full compile of code and thus work properly with IntelliJ and WebStorm so you can properly place breakpoints in the code and not have to use the ;debugger; string which v8 looks for...

hope this helps someone, sure helped me :)

Sean.

Comment: Note that the flag `debug-brk` is no longer supported. Instead use the new flag `inspect-brk` or `inspect-brk=9229` where 9229 is the port number on which you want the debugger to start.

Answer (score 15):

As others have said, you can see command line options for v8 with

```
node --v8-options
```

There, you can see a listing for `--lazy`:

```
--lazy (use lazy compilation)
      type: bool  default: true
```

v8 uses a fairly common way to describe booleans - prefix the flag with `no` to set to false, and use just the flag to set to true.  So `--nolazy` sets the `lazy` flag to false.

Note: `node` uses a slightly different convention - there, you use the `no-` prefix (note the dash) to set bools to false.  For example, `--no-deprecation` is a `node` flag.

Answer (score 13):

refer to: 
https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editor/debugging/

For performance reasons Node.js parses the functions inside JavaScript files lazily on first access. As a consequence, breakpoints don't work in source code areas that haven't been seen (parsed) by Node.js.

Since this behavior is not ideal for debugging, VS Code passes the --nolazy option to Node.js automatically. This prevents the delayed parsing and ensures that breakpoints can be validated before running the code (so they no longer "jump").

Since the --nolazy option might increase the start-up time of the debug target significantly, you can easily opt out by passing a --lazy as a runtimeArgs attribute.

Answer (score 4):

- **Problem:** when you want to set breakpoints in ides to debug `js` codes in `nodejs`, some `breakpoints` doesn't work.
- **Reason:** On start, node parses the code lazily, it means it doesn't see the full code. so it doesn't see all of the breakpoint.
- **Solution:** Use `--no-lazy` option to turn of the node's lazy behavior.

( Ps: i tried to explain it easily and it may not be so accurate. )

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
node --v8-options
```

it will show you all available flags.

btw: closest flag I have found for you is

```
--lazy
```

means lazy compilation, which I believe is obvious by name