# How to debug on a property's set in Visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, properties, breakpoints

Let's say I have this property

```
public ISetting Setting { get; set; }
```

How can I get breakpoint at the set? So that the program will pause when something is setting a value.

I try to make it this way

```
public IDatabaseConnectionSetting ConnectionSetting { 
    get; 
    set;
}
```

And put the breakpoint on the `set;` line, but still it doesn't work. The red breakpoint highlighter highlights the whole property declaration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a full property rather than autoproperty.

The shortcut is `propfull`

```
private ISetting setting;

public ISetting Setting 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return setting; 
    }
    set 
    { 
        setting = value; 
    }
}
```

To use the code-snippet shortcut, type `propfull` and then press `TAB` twice.

Comment: I find it weird if I have to change my code to full property just to debug it

Comment: @Louis yes, I agree and hopefully someone will answer with a new technique that I didn't know existed. But I know a lot of devs who code like `var result = blah.Evaluate; return result;` specifically so they can put a breakpoint on the return line & inspect what's being returned.  That's the same sort of thing.

Comment: Ok. Just curious, what do you mean by press tab twice? usually I type it, tab, type, tab, type.

Comment: When I type it and press `TAB` (just once) nothing happens and I'll just typing (e.g. I'll end up with `propfullint`) - I have to press `TAB` twice, then I can enter the type, then `TAB`, then the field name etc. Don't know why, that's how I thought it was.

Answer (score 7):

There's a better solution here: [Can't set breakpoints on an auto-property setter ? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682613/cant-set-breakpoints-on-an-auto-property-setter-why)

> Using Visual Studio 2008, 2010, 2012:
>
> 1. Go to the Breakpoint window
> 2. New->Break at Function…
> 3. For the get, type: ClassName.get_CurrentFramesize()
>
>    For the set, type: ClassName.set_CurrentFramesize(int)
>
> You'll get a "No Source Available" when the breakpoint is hit, but you'll get the calling >location in the call stack.
>
> I found this solution here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/b1dd0dc3-e9c1-402a-9c79-a5abf7f7286a
>
> See also: [Debugging automatic properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408110/debugging-automatic-properties)

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. Automatic properties are compiled like that one with backing store. I think there is no reason to allow breakpoints on them, because somewhere you must assign them, check your property there.

```
private bool TestProperty { get; set; }
```

is compiled like

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private bool <TestProperty>k__BackingField;
[CompilerGenerated]
private void set_TestProperty(bool value)
{
    this.<TestProperty>k__BackingField = value;
}
[CompilerGenerated]
private bool get_TestProperty()
{
    return this.<TestProperty>k__BackingField;
}
```

Comment: it could be set in any number of places - much more useful to break inside the setter than every place that calls the setter.

Comment: I agree.That should be feature of VS. May i ask what is your use case when you need call setters from many places? Just curious, thanks.